# How to use Cross Entropy loss in pytorch for binary prediction?

Tags: pytorch

In the pytorch docs, it says for cross entropy loss:

> input has to be a Tensor of size (minibatch, C)

Does this mean that for binary (0,1) prediction, the input must be converted into an (N,2) tensor where the second dimension is equal to (1-p)?

So for instance if I predict 0.75 for a class with target 1 (true), would I have to stack two values (0.75; 0.25) on top of each other as input?

Answer (score 3):

In Pytorch you can use cross-entropy loss for a binary classification task. You need to make sure to have two neurons in the final layer of the model. Make sure that you do not add a softmax function.

Use the below for resources:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/do-i-need-to-use-softmax-before-nn-crossentropyloss/16739

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-crossentropyloss-include-the-softmax-function/4420

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific loss in pytorch for your case :

- Just use the **binary cross entropy loss**

See the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cross%20entropy#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy) and [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cross%20entropy#torch.nn.BCELoss).

Answer (score 0):

So for Binary Prediction in Pytorch the ideal loss function would be the **Binary Cross Entropy Loss** which is available along with all the other error functions in the nn submodule in can be called as follows

```py
nn.BCELoss()
```

it has parameters reduction(mean and sum) and weights(pre-determined weightages). It's documentation can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=cross%20entropy#torch.nn.BCELoss)

Ensure that the predicted and the target variables are off the same shape and both of them are of type float.